# React Function is not using updated array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concurrency

I am learning React and am writing a React App that lets you press buttons that have values (1, 0, -1) and then does some calculations (average, %pos, etc).

[image]

I have written a function to calculate the average in my App.js component

```
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)
  const [allNum, setAll] = useState([])
  const [average, setAverage] = useState(0)

const calcAverage = () => {
  console.log('values in calcAvg for allNum: ', allNum)
  let total = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < allNum.length; i++) {
    total += allNum[i];
  }
  return total/allNum.length;
}

const handleGoodClick = () => {
  setGood(good + 1)
  setAll(allNum.concat(1))
  setAverage(calcAverage());
}
const handleNeutralClick = () => {
...
}
const handleBadClick = () => {
...
}


  return(
    <div>
     <h1>Give Feedback</h1>
     <Button handleClick={handleGoodClick} text="good"/>
     ...

     <Statistics good={good} neutral={neutral} bad={bad} allNum={allNum} average={average}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The Statistics component is as follows:

```
const Statistics = (props) => {
  console.log('props value is: ', props)
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Statistics</h1>
      ...
      <Statistic text="Average" value={props.average}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I press a button and the app attempts to calculate the average, the average array is always 1 value behind.

ie, open app, press good, Average shows as NaN, console.log shows the allNum array containing a 1 but when Average is calculated that 1 is not contained in the allNum array yet. Why doesn't it go in order? How can I make it execute in order? What is the best practice approach?

Thanks

Comment: The function returned by `useState` that is used to update the state is not synchronous, the state values will be updated before the next render cycle. To get around this you could use a `useEffect` to update the average whenever the `allNum` state changes. i.e. `useEffect(() => { /* calculate and setAverage here */ }, [allNum])`

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it? Is useEffect the most appropriate solution for an issue like this where we have to display information that is based upon calculations of the parent components state?

Comment: From what I can see here, I would most likely swap out the `useEffect` and `useState` used for `average` to be a singular `useMemo`, but it's hard to say without knowing  for sure everything that average needs to be influenced by. It's also worth noting that you could probably profile to see if memoization of `average` is even benefitial, it might just be better to recompute the value each render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the calculations receive the previous values is because the `setState` functions provided by `useState` do not set the state synchronously.

To overcome this you can use something like a `useEffect` to update average whenever `allNum` changes (reference comparison).

```
const MiscComponent = () => {
    const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
    const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
    const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)
    const [allNum, setAll] = useState([])
    const [average, setAverage] = useState(0)

    // The useEffect will trigger based on what is entered into the 
    // dependency array: [setAverage, allNum]
    // Each render cycle the values will be compared (reference comparison)
    // to the previous values in the dependency array and if there is a
    // change the effect will be run.
    // NOTE: There is always considered to be a "change" on component mount.

    // setAverage is guarenteed to never change reference once created by useState.
    // Someone else probably has the link to the React docs for this statement.

    // So everytime allNum is updated this effect should run.
    useEffect(() => {
        const average = allNum.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / allNum.length;

        setAverage(average)
    }, [setAverage, allNum])

    // Since the average update will be handled by the useEffect it can
    // now be removed from the click handler.
    const handleGoodClick = () => {
        setGood(good + 1)
        setAll(allNum.concat(1))
    }

    const handleNeutralClick = () => {
        /* Code here */
    }

    const handleBadClick = () => {
        /* Code here */
    }


    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Give Feedback</h1>
            <Button handleClick={handleGoodClick} text="good"/>
            {/* Components Here */}

            <Statistics good={good} neutral={neutral} bad={bad} allNum={allNum} average={average}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Another option if average is only ever effected (affected? whatever) by other state variables you could use a `useMemo` instead.

```
const MiscComponent = () => {
    const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
    const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
    const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)
    const [allNum, setAll] = useState([])

    // useMemo will return a memoized value for average that will only be recalculated
    // based on its associated dependency array.
    const average = useMemo(() => {
        const average = allNum.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / allNum.length;

        return average;
    }, [allNum]);

    // Since the average update will be handled by the useMemo it can
    // now be removed from the click handler.
    const handleGoodClick = () => {
        setGood(good + 1)
        setAll(allNum.concat(1))
    }

    const handleNeutralClick = () => {
        /* Code here */
    }

    const handleBadClick = () => {
        /* Code here */
    }


    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Give Feedback</h1>
            <Button handleClick={handleGoodClick} text="good"/>
            {/* Components Here */}

            <Statistics good={good} neutral={neutral} bad={bad} allNum={allNum} average={average}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```